# ChangePage error Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I made a Phonegap/cordova application with jQuery Mobile and jQuery.

In my code i have this to change my page :

```
changePage: function (url) {
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", url, {});
},
connexion : function() {
    if ($("#login").val() != "")
        login = $("#login").val();
    app.changePage('#pageScan');
},
```

This function work perfectly on my computer using ripple.

But when I start the application on my Android device (v : 4.4.4) and i use this function I got :

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object #pageScan has no method 'apply' "

I don't understand why it worked on Chrome desktop with Ripple and not in my phone.

There is my body (index.html) :

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageLogin">
        <div data-role="header" class="header">
            <input type="button" value="Connexion" onclick="app.connexion()">
            ...
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" id="connexion" class="content_appli">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageScan">
        <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus=""  >
           ....
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" id="contentPageScan" class="content_appli">
            ...
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" id="panelSettings">
            ...
        </div><!-- /panel -->

    </div> </body>
```

Comment: you pass url as a string `#pageScan` or an object `$("#pageScan")`?

Comment: i pass this : "#pageScan"

Comment: I just try with $("#pageScan") and it's the same error

Comment: Both should work anyway. It could be related to Android. Have you tried on different browsers? different devices?

Comment: No i got only my device and i need to have this application in android so i have to debug that

Comment: When do you change page?

Comment: After press a button in pageLogin : <input type="button" value="Connexion" onclick="app.connexion()"> 
connexion : function() {
        if ($("#login").val() != "")
            login = $("#login").val();
        app.changePage('#pageScan');
    },

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65347/discussion-between-omar-and-sagon-nicolas).